# JSON parsing in web socket server

Tags: json, html, node.js, websocket

I have created my web socket server and client using this simple tutorial here : http://cjihrig.com/blog/creating-your-own-node-js-websocket-echo-server/

But it seems like it recognises only UTF-8 characters.
I want to send JSON message in the text box:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify({"fname":"John","lname":"Smith"})
```

and in ws_server.js file, I have written

```
connection.on('message', function(message) {  
var jObject = JSON.parse(message); 
jObject.lname = "Jobs";  
}..
```

But I am getting error for JSON.parse method.

Please let me know what is the problem.
Or do I have to write any new server implementation for JSON parsing or JSON messages?

This is my client code: http://cjihrig.com/blog/creating-your-own-websocket-echo-client/
but value of "text" is modified to be as follows:
    jsonmsg = {fname:"John",lname:"Smith"}
    jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonmsg);
So      socket.send(jsonString);

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: what does the message param look like? console.log(message) and see what it looks like.

Comment: message param prints "Object". so it is an object and when I do console.log(message.type), it is giving me UTF-8!!

Comment: what happens if you don't do JSON.parse(message) and just use message.lname?

Comment: it is not working.. thorows error

Comment: can you post your client code?  how are you sending the message over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
socket.json.send( { fname : 'John', lname : 'Smith'} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonString = {"fname":"John","lname":"Smith"}
```

does not create a string; it creates an object. To make it a string:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify({"fname":"John","lname":"Smith"})
```

Comment: yes.. I am using the same .. But I have problem with parse method at server side.